# Issue localization in javascript

Tags: javascript, localization, abp

With Abp version 7.0 I customized the folder structure in a new project. For each project I created the Xep.Cms structure in which I moved all the files and folders of the starting project.

After this operation the localization on the site pages work correctly, but instead if I go to use the localization with some javascript code I get:

```
`WARN: 
Could not find localization source: AbpUi
WARN: 
Could not find localization source: AbpUi
Index.js initialized!
WARN: 
Could not find localization source: Cms`
```

What can I check to fix the problem?
Grazie

Running the project I get the error I attached and in the modal windows I don't see the localized text

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have overridden the layout. ABP 7.0 introduced a breaking change for localizations. You can see it here: https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Migration-Guides/Abp-7_0#external-localization-infrastructure.

You need to add the following line just before the `ApplicationConfigurationString` line:

```html
<script src="~/Abp/ApplicationLocalizationScript?cultureName=@CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name"></script>
```